# Database Schema API

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, oracle, database-schema

I'm looking for a tool that provides an API (preferably .Net) for querying the schema of multiple database platforms. I'm building a piece of software that would take the object model returned from such a tool and then analyse the schema and provide a custom query builder - I'd prefer to not have to write the schema analysis tool if I can avoid this.

Ideally it should be able to query all the major database platforms including MSSQL, Oracle, DB2, MySQL and possibly even Sybase. The Red Gate Schema Compare SDK does exactly what I need, but only for MSSQL.

Has anyone come across such a tool/library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, No.

Long answer.

I was looking to this myself a while ago but didn't find a free .Net API. All the ones I found cost money. I came up with two options

The first one is not a solution I recommend, but an option if you really don't want to write the "get DB metadata logic" yourself.

Visual query builder http://www.query-objects.com/  is a .Net query builder with a GUI. 
You could buy the source code license for it. Owning the source your can remove the UI and build your own API on top of that source code. It should work for MSSql, Oracle, MySql, and I guess any DB that supports ODBC.

The second and free solution is to try and write it yourself using this tutorial for example:

http://www.dotnetbips.com/articles/bcd9065e-94af-4063-8360-f916571f9872.aspx

The ADO.Net GetSchema method used here should give you a somewhat consistent way to get the Metadata from the different databases you mention.

Comment: I don't have any problems spending money on a component if it does what is required - the product we are building is for commercial purposes so any licencing costs we incur will be passed onto the end user. Where there any paid products you could recommend looking at?

Comment: Ok that would be the Active query builder, see http://www.activequerybuilder.com/product_net.html chapter "ADO.NET and custom metadata providers". The feature matrix  http://www.activequerybuilder.com/featurematrix.html?show=net

Comment: Thanks for the info, however we have used this product previously and it is horrible to work with and only works in IE due to it being a Active X control. I'm aware that they have a asp.net version in development but it has not really progressed anywhere in the last year.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but wouldn't the Mono project contain the code you are looking for?  If not for all databases, than I would expect at least for some of them.